# Laravel 5 Artisan::call dose not work correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

I use Laravel 5.5 and I have Controller like this.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
---------------------
public function index()
{
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
}
```

but it  not work correctly and show me this message in browser:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The connection was reset.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking the proxy 
>   the firewall
>
> Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

It already worked but it not work correctly now.

**Note1**: All commands in Artisan dose not work, for example `migrate,seed,...`

**Note2**: I install another laravl 5.5 script and test  `Artisan::call` method and it work correctly but it dose not work correctly in my script.

Comment: Can you provide few more details, like: Are you trying this locally or on a server somewhere. If locally, what's your setup (windows,mac,linux), do you use Vagrant with Homestead or something else. If you comment out ```Artisan::call('config:cache');``` and try to show some text, does it show when you access it in your browser? When you say that all commands does not work, have you tried them in the same setup, calling them from controller, or have you tried to run them from CLI? Same question for the new setup that you said it worked.

Comment: I'm in windows. Yes when I comment `Artisan::call('config:cache')` it's ok. In CLI command every thing is ok

Comment: This is weird, the error doesn't seem related to Laravel, is more like the server can't be reach. The weird part is that it works without this artisan call.

Comment: Perhaps this is a permissions issue. The user/group your webserver uses to work don't have permissions to `storage/framework/cache` folder, whereas the user/group you're using from console do have.